# Android how to run a task when app is in background of phone

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a service for the first time that runs a method from the activity every 15 seconds once a toggle button is checked when app is the background of a phone and so far the tutorials havent been helpful; this is my code so far. Forgive me if I look stupid here, its my first time using a service.

Service Code

```
package com.example.adrian.trucktracker;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class AutoUpdateService extends Service {
    Locator locator = new Locator();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    locator.TemperatureCatch();
                }
            }, 1000 );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 15000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTimer.cancel();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

My toggle button code

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
        {

startService(new Intent(this,AutoUpdateService.class));
        }
        else
        {
         stopService(new Intent(this,AutoUpdateService.class));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it right to use Service. Do not use Timer, since it is extra thread you do not need. What you can do is to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule your service intent to be launched every 15 seconds (interval). This will trigger interval time your service by calling onStartCommand in your service where you can do whatever you need by reading (if need) intent from parameters of onStartCommand.

Comment: could you please add an example? I'm unfamiliar with how to set out an alarm manager correctly

Comment: i've been trying to find an example of how to use the alarm manager and the service but i can't; can you please write one

Comment: after trying for a day to use an alarm manager ive found it complicated and arduous

Comment: how can i just use a service with a timer task